# Range hood impeller slipped on motor shaft

Tags: replacement, range-hood

The range  hood impeller slipped on motor shaft and  is fouling with the plastic housing. How can I pull it up by 3 mm ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would help us if you could post photos of the shaft/impeller. Often such impeller are secured by a set screw that can come loose and allow the impeller to slide up and down its shaft.

Comment: There is a good answer in your other post!

Answer (score 2):

If just the impeller/fan slipped on the shaft, it should only take a few light taps to slip it back in position.

The best way to tap is to use a small piece of pipe or a socket that just fits over the shaft.

The impeller should be locked to the shaft by a set screw or a clip.  The set screw is loose or the clip broke off.  Loosen the set screw a bit before tapping back in place.  When in place tighten the set screw tight to the shaft.

It is a possibility that the motor mounts came loose, causing the impeller to be lower.  Would check the mounts/screws for the motor if the impeller is tight on the shaft.

Do this work with the power turned off at the breaker.  You do not want to find yourself touching live power.

Comment: Also possible (even likely, if old, not new) that the bearings have worn, allowing the entire shaft/armature to move, rather than either the fan slipping on the shaft (loosen, move, retighten) or the mounting bolts loosening (retighten) which not infrequently means replacing the motor, as having it rebuilt depends on an infrastructure that is largely gone in the small household motors line, most places, circa 2022.

Comment: Thank you very much  ..will try as suggested